# SQLServer Order By IGNORE NULL values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

For some reason I can't change the table or update the data for now. Here the problem :

I have `menu_user` table below :

```
userID  menuID
(null)  2
(null)  3
1       3
2       1
3       2
4       5
5       0
```

`userID` and `menuID` not duplicated. The problem is how to `ORDER BY userID, menuID` but when `userID` has NULL value, it will look for another row that has same `menuID` and place it after this row. `menuID` just have max 2 same value and if it have, another one must be NULL

The order result expected :

```
userID  menuID
1       3
(null)  3
2       1
3       2
(null)  2
4       5
5       0
```

Here the script sample :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[menu_user](
    [userID] [int] NULL,
    [menuID] [int] NULL
);

INSERT [dbo].[menu_user] ([userID], [menuID]) VALUES (NULL, 3);
INSERT [dbo].[menu_user] ([userID], [menuID]) VALUES (1, 3);
INSERT [dbo].[menu_user] ([userID], [menuID]) VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT [dbo].[menu_user] ([userID], [menuID]) VALUES (3, 2);
INSERT [dbo].[menu_user] ([userID], [menuID]) VALUES (4, 5);
INSERT [dbo].[menu_user] ([userID], [menuID]) VALUES (5, 0);
INSERT [dbo].[menu_user] ([userID], [menuID]) VALUES (NULL, 2);
```

**ADDED** 
If possible I want this script as View (just SELECT with No Variable).

Comment: You won't be able to have it as a view. Views (like tables) have no inherent order - since this question is all about order, that's not going to work.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : I think you got it right, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do the trick. You need to do something to relate multiple rows together. Here I've chosen to use a `left join`:

```
select
    m1.*
from
    menu_user m1
        left join
    menu_user m2
        on
            m1.userID is null and
            m1.menuID = m2.menuID and
            m2.userID is not null
order by
    COALESCE(m1.userID,m2.userID),m1.userID desc
```

Result:

```
userID      menuID
----------- -----------
1           3
NULL        3
2           1
3           2
NULL        2
4           5
5           0
```

Hopefully you can see how it's achieving its aims.

Comment: Thank you very much, I got it fully understand by `select *`. And I'm sorry I didn't make full example, I modify the order to `COALESCE(m1.userID,m2.userID),m1.menuID,m1.userID desc`, I don't know why this is no work in sqlfiddle, but it is work really well in my sqlserver. Thank you http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/64ed35/2

Answer (score 0):

Check this, ordering is bit messed up but this gives you your desired result.

```
SELECT * FROM menu_user mu
ORDER BY mu.menuID,
CASE WHEN mu.userID IS NULL THEN mu.menuID END
```

Comment: it order by `menuID` at first, I need `userID` first but thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the left join solution will produce duplicates when there are more than 1 non-null Users for a menuID. This is another method.

```
select userID, menuID
From (
select *, Case when a.UseriD is not null then cast(a.userID as float) else
            (select max(b.userID) + 0.1 from menu_user b where a.menuID = b.menuID and a.userID is null) end as SortCol
    from menu_user a
) c Order by  SortCol
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM menu_user mu
WHERE userID IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY mu.menuID
```

Comment: Your query filters userID = null records. But Question clearly defines that null records also should be selected BUT ordered by unusual